# How to run CosmosDB emulator for Linux in a local kubernetes cluster

Tags: kubernetes, azure-cosmosdb, rancher-desktop

I would like to run a CosmosDB emulator linux docker image on a local kubernetes cluster. It does start: "evaluation period XX days and partition 1 of X started till N of N" is shown in the logging, but when connecting to port 8081 from outside (while forwarding that port from ingress) I can't connect to the explorer. Anyone who tried this and has a working setup?

Answer (score -1):

The Cosmos DB Linux Emulator is currently in preview mode and supports only the SQL and MongoDB APIs. We do not recommend use of the emulator (Preview) in production. For heavier workloads, use our [Windows emulator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/local-emulator).

```
Note : The emulator only supports MacBooks with Intel processors.
```

for more information you follow this [Microsoft document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/linux-emulator?tabs=sql-api%2Cssl-netstd21) also you can give feedback to `Cosmos DB Developer Experience Feedback<cdbportalfeedback@microsoft.com>` cdbportalfeedback@microsoft.com for you want to use this feature of azure for testing purpose.

Comment: I don't see how this answers the question?

Comment: Agree, want to run it within Kubernetes, this answer is very general